# FIWARE CEP (Proton) REST consumer stopped working after error and URL invalid charactes

Tags: rest, fiware, complex-event-processing

I'va noticed that if the requests send via REST consumer return an error (invalid scheme, connection refused, error 400, etc.) the REST consumer doesn't work anymore. To get it back, I had to reload the definition file.
I think that this may be a bug.

Moreover, during these tests, I've also noticed that not all the URL were accepted. For example, by omitting the "http://" Proton returns "invalid scheme" error. Whereas, URL with "-" isn't parsed correctly and the "connection refused" error is returned.
It'd very helpful to have a list of prohibited characters.

Thanks.

Comment: When you say you had to reload the definition file, did it include stop and start of the CEP, or stop and start of tomcat?

Comment: I opened two tickets in FIWARE development to investigate those issues:FIWARE.Bug.Data.CEP.Rest.ListOfInvalidURLCharacters, FIWARE.Bug.Data.CEP.Rest.ConsumerStoppedWorkingAfterInvalidCall

Comment: I just reload the definition file with {"action":"ChangeDefinitions", ...} at  /ProtonOnWebServerAdmin/resources/instances/ProtonOnWebServer.

Comment: Thanks for the details. Added to the relevant ticket